# IBM Worklight Plugin connection is not happening

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, phonegap-plugins

I have created cordova-plugin to make a native call in Android. In exec function of cordova plugin I have callbackContext through which I can call javascript function from cordova-plugin. The problem is Im  unable to call the javascript function through callbackContext after certain amount of time.

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)
throws JSONException {
    if (NFC_INIT_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        WalletRuntimeStore.setContext(context);
        nfc = NFCService.getInstance();
        HelloWorldPlugin(data, callbackContext);
        return true;
    }
```

if Im calling HelloWorldPlugin within the execute method its working if i call it outside the execute method is not working...

Comment: And how would you like us to help you? Edit the question and explain in detail how did you create the plug-in, whether you've declared it in config.xml, provide code snippets (or even a demo project) and any error messages you've noticed.

Comment: Yes i had declared in config.xml.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem completely, but remember that you only have the CallbackContext variable available in the execute method, so the only way you can pass it to another function would be to call it from within the execute method, but you can pass the callbackContext to another function, even in another thread, and call it whenever you are done. I hope this helps. If not, please edit the question with more details.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I have resolved it. The issue was with the thread management. Also sorry that I did not gave more information & code earlier. Thanks again.

Comment: @manjakannar, please write your answer below and mark as Answered.

Comment: It was my mistake, I was causing the main thread wait, hence none of the operations were being performed on Main thread. Removed the wait call & everything started to work. The correct way to make use of callback context is to use setKeepCallback function available in PluginResult class. All i did was wrote the below code in exec function of CordovaPlugin:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake, I was causing the main thread to wait, hence none of the operations were being performed on Main thread. Removed the wait call & everything started to work. The correct way to make use of callback context is to use setKeepCallback function available in PluginResult class. 
Send a no result callback to javascript:

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
// some code....
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
result.setKeepCallback(true);
callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
// some code....
}
```

later(probably after a network call or any long term operation) the callback can be sent to javascript function by using:

```
PluginResult result1 = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, data);
result1.setKeepCallback(true);
callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result1);
```

Optionally we can also call javascript function from java code by getting webview refrence from cordova plugin & by using sendJavascript function.